# Custom Credential Provider

Tags: c++, credentials, credential-providers

I have built a custom Credential Provider which is provided as a sample in Windows SDK. It is working great on computers.

the problem comes when the CR is installed on a remote server and people connect to it through RDP , the user is prompted twice for his username/password pairs, the first time in native rdp client and the second time in the custom credential provider itself when he logs in successfully through the native rdp client.

is there a way to grab the username and password which were entered in the first step and write it on the CR fields.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. For security reasons, in this particular case Microsoft forces users to authenticate twice.

See [RDC and Custom Credential Providers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/07/14/rdc-and-custom-credential-providers/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the [UpdateRemoteCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialproviderfilter-updateremotecredential) in your filter.